# Why does Asp.Net Core 2.1 WebApi return a 500.19 error?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a small webapi service, which works under Visual Studio but doesn't work under IIS.
I did the next:

1. New application was added to the default web-site in IIS console.
2. Application was published into app folder from VS via File System
   (Framework-dependent and Portable options were selected).

When I try access folder with my app (like `http://localhost/example/`) I receive `500.19` error with code `0x8007000d`. I read this error can happen if `ApplicationHost.config` or `Web.config` has wrong XML options. I use default  `Web.config` file (`ApplicationHost.config` is not used by me) which VS generate, and I don't understand what can be bad in it. Here's my `Web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Service.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-story-of-publishing-net-core-web-apps-for-beginners-6121662dd8c4

Comment: @LexLi, thank you! My problem was I hadn't  ASP.NET Core Module installed. Now it works.

Comment: @Miamy: Please post the resolution as an answer, and accept it when you can. Otherwise, this question will remain in the unanswered queue indefinitely.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I thought to do it myself yesterday before sleep :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lex Li wrote an excellent article: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-story-of-publishing-net-core-web-apps-for-beginners-6121662dd8c4, which described issues with publishing .NET Core Web Apps.

In my case, I hadn't installed the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle. A simple solution which is hard to be found because it is difficult to understand what should be searched for.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue and in addition to the marked correct answer, this is what worked for me:

I installed the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle and was still receiving the same error.

**Repairing** the installation resolved my issue.

[Programs and Features -> Repair "Windows Server Hosting"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GZxf.png)

*"If the Hosting Bundle is installed before IIS, the bundle installation must be repaired. Run the Hosting Bundle installer again after installing IIS.
If the Hosting Bundle is installed after installing the 64-bit (x64) version of .NET Core, SDKs might appear to be missing (No .NET Core SDKs were detected). To resolve the problem, see Troubleshoot ASP.NET Core projects."* - [Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x&source=post_page-----6121662dd8c4----------------------#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).